# Magento 2 pwa FetchError: invalid json response body at https://xxx/graphql reason: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0

Tags: magento2, json, pwa, pwa-studio, yarn

Magento 2 PWA

When we run the command "`yarn run watch`" then getting this error on the console -

`FetchError: invalid json response body at https://xxx/graphql reason: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0`

Following that link - https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/pwa-studio/tutorials/setup-storefront/

Even on .env file URL is properly set -

```
MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL=https://xxx
```

Anyone knows how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am fetching this error when I apply commands yarn run watch commands. but I have a solution below step.

Step 1: First I will change my PHP version php8.1 to php 8.2

=> sudo a2dismod php8.1

=> sudo a2enmod php8.2

=> sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.2

=> sudo service apache2 restart

After i go to magento 2 root directory and app/etc/env.php

change

```
 'session' => [
    'save' => 'file'
],
```

to

```
  'session' => [
    'save' => 'db'
],
```

after applying the below commands

```
sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && php bin/magento c:f && chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/ app/etc
```

I hope to help with this solution.